# What benefit can I get from using Repository pattern with ORM

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

Why should I use Repository Pattern when EF already have implemented it.

If you are using just ado.net without any ORM maybe in this situation it should be better to use Repository Pattern. Consider an example

Here is the test repository code

```
public class TestRepository
{
    public void Create()
    {
        // Create logic
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        // Update logic
    }

    public void Remove()
    {
        // Remove logic
    }

    public void Read()
    {
        // Read operation
    }
}
```

So if I want to for example delete record I can make new instance of TestRepository and call Remove method. What happened inside Remove method :

```
_dbContext.Test.Remove(Something);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I'm calling TestRepository Remove method for remove something from database and this Remove method calls Remove method from Entity framework for remove record.

What benefit I can get from Repository Pattern with Entity framework ? 
It is not wasting time to use repository pattern which is already implemented in entity framework ?

Comment: Have a look at this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: It's opinion based. But from my experience, Repository Pattern with EF causes more problems rather then solving them. And makes simple things harder.

Comment: This is an opinionated question, but IMO, you win nothing by the double Repository implementation. The only real benefit would be needing to remove EF from the solution. Also, notice that Entity Framework also implements the Unit of Work pattern (through the `DbSet` class)

Comment: I think you've answered your own question.

Comment: Huh, there's no option to flag a question as belonging on the [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) page of stack exchange...but that's probably where this question should be.

Comment: "It was very good to have repository pattern ontop of EF when we decided to change ORM".. said no one ever

Comment: If you end up with one-liner respository methods that call EF, then ditch the repository. I *have* seen cases where considerable logic is placed in the repository layer (for whatever reason), so it makes sense to have a separate repository.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework implements more general pattern called 'Unit of work' ( https://cpratt.co/repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework/ ).
If you don't need to test your code which will work with DAL, then you can use EF without additional level of abstraction. But EF is just an implementation of Repository ( and Unit of Work ) pattern. Are you sure that you won't find any better implementation? If you are, then use EF directly.

Answering your question, I think it strongly depends on complexity of your application and your needs.
Additional abstraction over EF will allow you to simplify testing and also it will let you change EF to some modern ORM or micro-ORM like Dapper. According to my experience, this opportunity is very cool.

Comment: You can mock the dbContext. So testing EF directly is not a problem.

Comment: Sure, there are a lot of articles and libraries which allow us to do it, but anyway it's a bit more difficult than mocking an interface like IRepository.